# How to implement user authentication in spring-boot 3.0.6 using spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am currently working on a SpringBoot application for user registration and authentication. The user registration part is working as expected but the issue comes when I want to authenticate the user. The I am not getting any error but seems tha app is not authenticating the user details i provide instead it redirects me to the login page. I am new to the framework so i have implemented all the code from entity class to security configurations. The following are sample of my code.

**User.java**

```
package com.forensics.satiya.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public User(String firstname, String lastname, String email, String password, List<Role> roles) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

The above is my user entity class which I used lombok annotation to reduce the boilerplate code.

**UserRepository.java**

```
package com.forensics.satiya.repository;

import com.forensics.satiya.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

**UserServices.java**

```
package com.forensics.satiya.service;

import com.forensics.satiya.dto.AuthenticationRequest;
import com.forensics.satiya.dto.UserRegistrationDto;
import com.forensics.satiya.model.Role;
import com.forensics.satiya.model.User;
import com.forensics.satiya.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.forensics.satiya.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServices  {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    public User save(UserRegistrationDto registrationDto) {
        //Optional<Role> role = roleRepository.findByName(registrationDto.getRole());
        User user = new User(
                registrationDto.getFirstname(),
                registrationDto.getLastname(),
                registrationDto.getEmail(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(registrationDto.getPassword()),
                Arrays.asList(new Role("USER")));
        //Collections.singletonList(role.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Role not found in the database"))));
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
        System.out.println("User saved to the database: " + savedUser.toString());

        return savedUser;

    }

    public void authenticate(AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        authenticationRequest.getEmail(),
                        authenticationRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
       System.out.println("user authentication was successful");
    }
        //return "redirect:/accounts/success";
}
```

For Security configurations I used two different classes, the SecurityConfiguration and the AppConfig class because when I tried to have my configurations and `@Bean` in the same class, i was getting an error for cycling dependencies so below are my configurations.

***SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.forensics.satiya.config;

import com.forensics.satiya.service.UserService;
import com.forensics.satiya.service.UserServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/accounts/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .build();
    }
    //there should be a DaoAuth method here when undoing
}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
package com.forensics.satiya.config;

import com.forensics.satiya.model.Role;
import com.forensics.satiya.model.User;
import com.forensics.satiya.repository.UserRepository;
import com.forensics.satiya.service.UserService;
import com.forensics.satiya.service.UserServices;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppConfig {

    private final UserRepository repository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return username -> {
            User user = repository.findByEmail(username);
            if(user == null){
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
            }
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
        };
    }
    private Collection<?extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles){
        return roles.stream().map(role-> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception{
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

The following is the authentication request class, which I used to get the user email and the password for authentication.

**AuthenticationRequest.java**

```
package com.forensics.satiya.dto;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class AuthenticationRequest {
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

Lastly here is my controller for login.

**HomeController.java**

```
package com.forensics.satiya.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {


    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginPage(Model model) {

        return "login";
    }
}
```

The following is my login form:

**login.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>login</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>User login</h1>
            <form action=""   method="post">
<!--                error message  -->
                <div th:if="${param.error}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        invalid username or password.
                    </div>
                </div>

<!--                logout message -->
                <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        you have been logged out.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="control-label">Username or email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                           placeholder="enter email address" autofocus="autofocus"  required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="type password"
                    required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Log in</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Does not have account? <a th:href="@{/accounts/register}">register here</a></span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using the SpringBoot MVC and I want my code to authenticate a user and if the authentication is successful the application must redirect the user to the registration page which is has a url `/accounts/register`. I am also using MySQL database and the spring-security dependency is also added to my `pomo.xml`. The user registration is working fine therefore I didn't provided the controller which is regitering the user.

After editind my home controller to submit the app is still not authenticating, instead it is returning the same login url with an error parameter `http://localhost:8080/login?error`.

Comment: You shouldn't as that is (and should be) left to Spring security. You should post a username and password to the `/login` url which will be then handled by Spring security. You then should remove the login part from your controller and user service.

Comment: I have edited the HomeController to submit to ```/login``` but it is returning a url ```http://localhost:8080/login?error``` which indicates there is an error, how can I make the code work, are my ```@Bean``` correct in the configurations?